# Algorithm for finding the intersection of reflecting beams within a region

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, intersection

I am currently working on a ultrasonic testing related program. Referring to the image below:

[image]

I have the black box as a probe, with 2 black lines as the beam radiating outwards, hitting the bottom surface and reflecting to intersect (intersection marked by the black dots) with the boundaries of the triangle (outlined by the blue lines).

I understand that given all the parameters (such as the equations of every line and the beam angles), I could solve for the position of the black dots using simple trigonometry.

However, my question is that is there a better/advanced method of solving such an issue? (For example, using some form of Winding Number algorithm, similar to the point in polygon problem).
I am assuming that all parameters (angle of the beams, exact position and orientation of the probe and the triangle) are known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's much out of the ordinary you can use here. The calculation of the intersection points is fairly straightforward.

With the x direction left to right, and y bottom to top, let's say that we the bottom horizontal line is at `y1` and the top at `y2`, and we have two line segments, with x coordinates for the start/end points of the two segments as indicated:

```
        x4     x2
y2 -------------------
         \    /
          \  /
           \/
           /\
          /  \
         /    \
        /      \
y1 -------------------
       x1      x3
```

The parameterized form of the two line segments is then:

```
( x1 + t1 * (x2 - x1), y1 + t1 * (y2 - y1) )
( x3 + t2 * (x4 - x3), y1 + t2 * (y2 - y1) )
```

The intersection point is calculated by finding the values of `t1` and `t2` where both points are the same. From setting the two y values equal, we can quickly see that `t1` and `t2` must be equal:

```
y1 + t1 * (y2 - y1) = y1 + t2 * (y2 - y1)
t1 * (y2 - y1) = t2 * (y2 - y1)
t1 = t2
```

Knowing this, we can substitute `t1` for `t2`, set the x values to be equal, and solve the equation for `t1`:

```
x1 + t1 * (x2 - x1) = x3 + t1 * (x4 - x3)
t1 * ((x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3)) = x3 - x1
t1 = (x3 - x1) / ((x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3))
```

Once you calculated `t1`, you know that the segments intersect if its value is between 0.0 and 1.0. If it is, the intersection point `(xt, yt)` is obtained by substituting it into one of the segment equations. The whole thing then becomes (pseudo code):

```
t1 = (x3 - x1) / ((x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3))
if t1 >= 0.0 and t1 <= 1.0
    xi = x1 + t1 * (x2 - x1)
    yi = y1 + t1 * (y2 - y1)
else
    no intersection
```

You could try to improve this. For example, you can decide that certain configurations do not intersect just based on comparing coordinates, without doing the full calculation. But since the calculation itself is so simple, it hardly seems worth it.

Comment: I get the idea, but I don't really understand why is the t for both lines the same? Shouldn't it be t_1 and t_2 instead?

Comment: @JohnTan Yes, I believe the result was correct, but the way I derived it was not clean. I updated the answer. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. Just curious, is this a standard way of calculating line intersection in computer graphics? I would not have thought of using parameterized form of equations to solve this problem.